# Spark sql Dataframe joins what's going on?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, for simplicity lets call them left and right and I'll just show sample structure.

Dataframe "left": (this dataframe is quite large)

```
src  | dst
------------
b    | a
c    | b
a    | c
```

Dataframe "right" (this dataframe is tiny)

```
loc  | name
------------
a    | London
b    | Paris
```

Both these dataframes are created using a hive context and an sql statement.

If I run a join on the left dataframe as follows everything works fine:

```
left.join(right, left("src") === right("loc"), "left_outer")
```

This returns me a dataframe with the join as expected

What I am actually trying to do is do the match on both the col1 and col2 in effect trying to return the following

```
src | dst | src_loc | src_name | dst_loc | dst_name
---------------------------------------------------
b   | a   | b       | Paris    | a       | London
c   | b   | null    | null     | b       | Paris
a   | c   | a       | London   | null    | null
```

If I try do that on the dataframes as follows the entire Spark job falls over, it doesn't error but it either takes way too long or something is going on that I don't understand.

```
val dfjoin1 = left.join(right, left("src") === right("loc"), "left_outer")
dfjoin1.join(right, dfjoin1("dst") === right("loc"), "left_outer")
```

Out of frustration I tried rather than reusing the right dataframe, to create a new one from a second identical hive query

The following works but to me seems very wrong (shouldn't need to call hive twice for the same data)

```
val right = hiveContext.sql(FROM .....)
val right2 = hiveContext.sql(FROM .....)

val dfjoin1 = left.join(right, left("src") === right("loc"), "left_outer")
dfjoin1.join(right2, dfjoin1("dst") === right2("loc"), "left_outer")
```

The ext problem I have is that I want to filter on the columns that have been added, for argument sake lets say I want to get all ones where the src loc name is Paris.

```
dfjoin1.filter($"name" === "Paris")
```

This fails because of ambiguous column names.  How do I solve this issue?  Can I prefix the columns with a name easily as part of the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure - but I think the cause for the failure is column ambiguity as well - when you compare `dfjoin1("dst") === right("loc")` you might actually be comparing `dst` to the `loc` column that was joined by the previous join operation.

In other words, I believe both your issues can be solved by more accurate column naming which would make sure there are no ambiguities. The easier way to achieve this (and get the output schema you want) is to **rename** columns after each join:

```
val result = left
  .join(right, $"src" === $"loc", "left_outer")
  .withColumnRenamed("loc", "src_loc")
  .withColumnRenamed("name", "src_name")
  .join(right, $"dst" === $"loc", "left_outer") // "loc" is now non-ambiguous, because we renamed left's "loc"
  .withColumnRenamed("loc", "dst_loc")
  .withColumnRenamed("name", "dst_name")

result.show()
// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
// |src|dst|src_loc|src_name|dst_loc|dst_name|
// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
// |  b|  a|      b|   Paris|      a|  London|
// |  c|  b|   null|    null|      b|   Paris|
// |  a|  c|      a|  London|   null|    null|
// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
```

An alternative approach can use `DataFrame.as(String)` to name the right dataframe before using it, each time with different names. The result is slightly different but still usable:

```
left
  .join(right.as("src"), $"src" === $"src.loc", "left_outer")
  .join(right.as("dst"), $"dst" === $"dst.loc", "left_outer")
  .show()

// +---+---+----+------+----+------+
// |src|dst| loc|  name| loc|  name|
// +---+---+----+------+----+------+
// |  b|  a|   b| Paris|   a|London|
// |  c|  b|null|  null|   b| Paris|
// |  a|  c|   a|London|null|  null|
// +---+---+----+------+----+------+
```

The schema shows two columns with same name for `loc` and `name`, but they can actually be referenced with the relevant prefixes, e.g. `src.name` or `dst.loc`.

Comment: Would there be any way to prefix all columns in a join or do I need to do a withColumnRenamed on every column?  I have around 30 columns in the right table which means having approx 60 rename statements, seems a little overkill but I guess may be necessary.

Comment: I wonder if this would actually solve the "entire Spark job falls over, it doesn't error but it either takes way too long or something is going on" issue - comment if it doesn't!

Comment: Will do, I'll be able to test on the full dataset Monday.  left table is around a billion results but could be more at times.  Right table is a few thousand records at most.

Comment: I've added an answer below with a slight modification to the withColumn variation.  I've tested on my local datasets and seems to work OK, not had a chance to test on large dataset yet.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Tzach Zohar, as mentioned in the comments if you have a lot of columns, renaming them becomes pretty ugly.  To get around this you can use the table schema to get the names of the columns and prepend a name to all of them as follows:

```
var tmp = left.join(right,$"src" === $"loc", "left_outer")

right.schema.fields.foreach { x => tmp = tmp.withColumnRenamed(x.name, "src_" + x.name) }

tmp = tmp.join(right,$"dst" === $"loc", "left_outer")

right.schema.fields.foreach { x => tmp = tmp.withColumnRenamed(x.name, "dst_" + x.name) }

// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
// |src|dst|src_loc|src_name|dst_loc|dst_name|
// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
// |  b|  a|      b|   Paris|      a|  London|
// |  c|  b|   null|    null|      b|   Paris|
// |  a|  c|      a|  London|   null|    null|
// +---+---+-------+--------+-------+--------+
```